# c# using previous instances of classes and forms

Tags: c#, forms, class

briefly, I'm trying to set a checkBox shown in Form1 checked or unchecked from a button that is in Form2. 
But after watching many videos, searching in tutorials I realized that the problem I'm currently facing it's reduced to: I don't understand how to access to a Class properties from another when the instance of the first is already "made".

Let's say I created a WindowFormApplication, wich has a Form1.cs: (here goes an example)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string someVariable;
    int moreVariables;

    public void someMethods()
    {
    //work with textBoxes, checkBoxes, etc
    }
//generate a new instance of a random class
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.name = textBox1.Text;
p1.age = Int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

}
```

suppouse I have another form, Form2.cs

how can I use the same Person data (p1) in Form2 ?
the only way I know to use an instance is creating a new one, like I did in Form1.
and how do I acces to checkBoxes, etc in Form1? (they are setted like public)

I don't expect you to write a solution to my actual problem, but a brief explanation, a link to a tutorial or video so I can finally understand how to deal with this in other circumstances.

Thanks, and sorry for being reiterative.

Comment: Well, I found a way to reference to default instance of form1, so I can acces to it's properties.
inside the form1 declare:
public static Form1 theInstance= null;

then, set 
theInstance = this;

and then, you can call it from another form like: Form1.theInstance.

Answer (score 0):

Use static variable in Form1:

```
static Person p1;
p1 = new Person();
```

In form2, reference p1 with code:

```
Form1.p1.xxx = yyy;
```

If you have multiple instance of Form1, do as below:

Form1:

```
public Person p1 {get;set;}
```

Form2:

```
Form1 instance1= new (...);
instnace1.p1.xxx= yyy;

Form1 instance2= new (...);
instnace2.p1.xxx= yyy;
```

Comment: And what if there are multiple instances of the window?

Comment: or if I want to acces to, for example, buttons or checkboxes of the form. That was another doubt I had, I dont make an instance of the Form1, how can I refer to it if I never made an instance like I did with Person.

Comment: Use static variable then.